# TYPO3 Calendar Module with icloud

Tags: php, typo3, icalendar

How to connect i-cloud account calendar to TYPO3 Calendar link? I am not familiar with TYPO3. How to edit in TYPO3 and save data?

Answer (score 0):

This is no easy task and I'm not sure if writing to the iCloud calendar is possible through the iCloud API. If you're unfamiliar with TYPO3, I don't see much of a chance to do this within reasonable time.

This is how reading a calendar could work:

- Retrieve CalDAV URLs of your iCloud account, inspiration could be this PHP script: https://github.com/muhlba91/icloud
- Import the CalDAV data to TYPO3 and display it in a calendar. There is a CalDAV extension for the extension "cal", see here: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/caldav/current/. But I don't recommend using extension "cal" since it is some kind of a monster extension that is hard to configure.